# Substitute text Data from two different columns

Tags: vba, excel

I want to remove single word from multiple words separated by comma:

I Want a macro that should work for all sheets in workbook.

I have the following data in Column A in Sheet1, Sheet2, Sheet3. 
The no of rows and data differ for different sheets.

```
Little Nicobar
Mildera
Mus
Nancowrie
Nehrugram
Pilomilo Island
```

and Following data in Column Q:

```
Little Nicobar,Mildera,Mus,Nancowrie,Nehrugram,Pilomilo Island
Little Nicobar,Mildera,Mus,Nancowrie,Nehrugram,Pilomilo Island
Little Nicobar,Mildera,Mus,Nancowrie,Nehrugram,Pilomilo Island
Little Nicobar,Mildera,Mus,Nancowrie,Nehrugram,Pilomilo Island
Little Nicobar,Mildera,Mus,Nancowrie,Nehrugram,Pilomilo Island
Little Nicobar,Mildera,Mus,Nancowrie,Nehrugram,Pilomilo Island
```

Want output in Column R as follows:

```
Mildera,Mus,Nancowrie,Nehrugram,Pilomilo Island
Little Nicobar,Mus,Nancowrie,Nehrugram,Pilomilo Island
Little Nicobar,Mildera,Nancowrie,Nehrugram,Pilomilo Island
Little Nicobar,Mildera,Mus,Nehrugram,Pilomilo Island
Little Nicobar,Mildera,Mus,Nancowrie,Pilomilo Island
Little Nicobar,Mildera,Mus,Nancowrie,Nehrugram
```

Means i want remove word in column A from Column R.

For this we can use the formula in R1

```
=TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(Q1,A1,""))
```

But its only working for R1.

I want a macro that provides the desired output and should work for all sheets. As the different data present in Sheet1, sheet2...sheetn.
Help me.

Comment: Does your data have headers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
Sub test()
    Dim vDB, vData, vR()
    Dim s As String
    Dim Ws As Worksheet
    Dim i As Long, n As Long
    For Each Ws In Worksheets
        With Ws
            vDB = .Range("a1", .Range("a" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
            n = UBound(vDB, 1)
            vData = .Range("q1").Resize(n)
            ReDim vR(1 To n, 1 To 1)
            For i = 1 To n
                s = Replace(vData(i, 1), vDB(i, 1), "")
                s = Replace(s, ",,", ",")
                If Left(s, 1) = "," Then
                    Mid(s, 1, 1) = Space(1)
                End If
                If Right(s, 1) = "," Then
                    Mid(s, Len(s), 1) = Space(1)
                End If
                vR(i, 1) = Trim(s)
            Next i
            .Range("r1").Resize(n) = vR
        End With
    Next Ws
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Dy.Lee, Perfect solution. Simple and Superb

Answer (score 0):

Write this formula in R1 and drag down

```
=SUBSTITUTE(Q1,","&A1,"")
```

Comment: Thanks its working. But how can i apply this to all sheets?

Comment: Use [Autofill](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Fill-data-automatically-in-worksheet-cells-74e31bdd-d993-45da-aa82-35a236c5b5db). Just insert on first row and autofill it. Or create a VBA to autofill it

Answer (score 0):

I feel like this is definitely possible with excel functions as VB seems like overkill. This puts your large string in col Q into an array and removes whatever the value in col A is. See my answer below and let me know if you have any issues. This is also assuming your data doesn't have headers.

```
Sub ReplaceThings()

    Dim wbk As Workbook
    Dim wksht As Worksheet
    Dim RemoveMe As String, myList() As String, myText As String
    Dim Cell As Range
    Dim x As Long, lRow As Long, p As Long

    Set wbk = Workbooks("StackOverflow.xlsm") 'Change this to your workbook name

    'Loop through each worksheet in workbook
    For Each wksht In wbk.Worksheets
        With wksht
            'Find last row
            lRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
            For Each Cell In .Range("A1:A" & lRow)
                RemoveMe = Cell.Value
                'Fill array with data in Column Q
                myList = Split(Cell.Offset(0, 16).Value, ",")
                For x = LBound(myList) To UBound(myList)
                    'Loop through array and check if RemoveMe is in Array
                    If myList(x) = RemoveMe Then
                        'Remove value from array
                        For p = x To UBound(myList) - 1
                            myList(p) = myList(p + 1)
                        Next p
                        Exit For
                    End If
                Next x
                'Print value to column Q
                For x = LBound(myList) To UBound(myList)
                    If x = 0 Then
                        myText = myText & myList(x)
                    Else
                        myText = myText & "," & myList(x)
                    End If
                Next x
                Cell.Offset(0, 17) = myText
                myText = ""
                Erase myList
            Next Cell
        End With
    Next wksht

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.But giving error on line 9, I ma be doing some mistake at renaming the worksheet. Got the Solution from Lee .Thanks for your time.