# Transpose data based on reference value then substract text from output

Tags: excel, vba

I have the village-urls in column A, in column J respective district name the village belongs to. I want to tanspose all the vilalge-urls separated by comma to column R execpt the value in column A. Transpose should done based on comparitive value J(Dist).

```
So every R2=R2-A2
```

Macro should work for all worksheets.

Input:

Column A Values:

```
URL
<a href="https://D.COM/Campbelbay" >Campbelbay</a>,
<a href="https://D.COM/Carnicobar" >Carnicobar</a>,
<a href="https://D.COM/Champin" >Champin</a>,
<a href="https://D.COM/Aerial-Bay" >Aerial Bay</a>,
<a href="https://D.COM/Bakultala" >Bakultala</a>,
<a href="https://D.COM/Betapur" >Betapur</a>,
<a href="https://D.COM/Diglipur" >Diglipur</a>,
<a href="https://D.COM/Aberdeen-Bazar" >Aberdeen Bazar</a>,
<a href="https://D.COM/Bambooflat" >Bambooflat</a>,
<a href="https://D.COM/Beachdera" >Beachdera</a>,
<a href="https://D.COM/Beodnabad" >Beodnabad</a>,
```

Column J Values:

```
DISTRICT
Nicobar
Nicobar
Nicobar
North And Middle Andaman
North And Middle Andaman
```

Output:

```
MERGEDURL
    <a href="https://D.COM/Carnicobar" >Carnicobar</a>,<a href="https://D.COM/Champin" >Champin</a>,<a href="https://D.COM/Aerial-Bay" >Aerial Bay</a>,<a href="https://D.COM/Bakultala" >Bakultala</a>
<a href="https://D.COM/Campbelbay" >Campbelbay</a>,<a href="https://D.COM/Champin" >Champin</a>,<a href="https://D.COM/Aerial-Bay" >Aerial Bay</a>,<a href="https://D.COM/Bakultala" >Bakultala</a>
<a href="https://D.COM/Campbelbay" >Campbelbay</a>,<a href="https://D.COM/Carnicobar" >Carnicobar</a>,<a href="https://D.COM/Aerial-Bay" >Aerial Bay</a>,<a href="https://D.COM/Bakultala" >Bakultala</a>
<a href="https://D.COM/Campbelbay" >Campbelbay</a>,<a href="https://D.COM/Carnicobar" >Carnicobar</a>,<a href="https://D.COM/Champin" >Champin</a>,<a href="https://D.COM/Bakultala" >Bakultala</a>
<a href="https://D.COM/Campbelbay" >Campbelbay</a>,<a href="https://D.COM/Carnicobar" >Carnicobar</a>,<a href="https://D.COM/Champin" >Champin</a>,<a href="https://D.COM/Aerial-Bay" >Aerial Bay</a>
```

Macro Used to Merge :

```
Sub Transpose()
Dim w As Excel.Worksheet
Dim r As Excel.Range

For Each w In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    Set r = w.Range("a2", w.Range("a1").End(xlDown))
    w.Range("q1").Value = Join(Application.Transpose(r), ",")
Next w
```

End Sub

Thanks for your time.

Credit and Refrence Macros:[VBA Provided by Imran Malek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5272396/imran-malek):

[Substitute Text macro provided here by Lee](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46526305/substitute-text-data-from-two-different-columns)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understood your problem.

```
Sub trans()
    Dim vDB, vData, vR(), vResult()
    Dim s As String, s2 As String
    Dim Ws As Worksheet
    Dim i As Long, n As Long
    For Each Ws In Worksheets
        With Ws
            vDB = .Range("a1", .Range("a" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
            n = UBound(vDB, 1)
            ReDim vR(1 To n): ReDim vResult(1 To n, 1 To 1)
            For i = 1 To n
                vR(i) = vDB(i, 1)
            Next i
            For i = 1 To n
                s = vR(i)
                vR(i) = Empty
                s2 = Join(vR, "")
                Mid(s2, Len(s2), 1) = Space(1)
                vResult(i, 1) = Trim(s2)
                vR(i) = s
            Next i
            .Range("r1").Resize(n) = vResult
        End With
    Next Ws
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Lee, again you are at my help. I want the column A values merged and added to column R based on corresponding value in column J.So the value in J changes then merging of corresponding values in column A starts freshly skipping respective cell value in column A and adds result to column R.